# java 8 lambda myMap.stream().count() != myMap.size() after merging myMap

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, eclipselink, java-stream

EDIT: I found this beeing a bug of eclipse link: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433075

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

In a JUnit test I found unexpected behaviour. As you can see the last assertion fails, because the stream seems to contain no data, while the map is not empty?! I found out, that it has something to do with jpa/eclipselink.

```
public class MyTest {
    private EntityManager em;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
            String dbFileName = "testDb.db";
            Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_URL, "jdbc:sqlite:"
                    + dbFileName);
            EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pul", properties);
            this.em = factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Test
    public void testStrange() {
        LV lv = new LV();
        // em.persist(lv); // this would work
        // em.merge(lv); // this would work as well
        lv = em.merge(lv); // this leads to the assertionError
        lv.getAms().add(new AM());
        assertEquals(1, lv.getAms().size()); // ok
        assertEquals(1, lv.getAms().stream().count()); // java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1> but was:<0>
    }
}
```

LV:

```
@Entity
public class LV {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long _id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "lv", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<AM> ams = new HashSet<AM>();

    public LV() {
    }

    public Collection<AM> getAms() {
        return ams;
    }

}
```

AM:

```
@Entity
public class AM {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long _id;

    @ManyToOne
    private LV lv;

    public AM() {
    }

}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="pul" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
            <!-- url is set during runtime -->
            <!-- <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:sample.db" 
                /> -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

            <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                value="database" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Knowing the types of `lv.getAbstractModules()` and `getKurzbezeichnung()` might help.

Comment: Your exact code worked for me (showing a consistent number of items in the list), when I set up dummy classes with those method names. So I can only suggest that your `lv.getAbstractModules()` method is not returning the same list over time.

Comment: Are you by any chance using a custom `List` implementation that may have a broken `stream()` method?

Comment: no, I use a HashSet for storing `AbstractModule`s in LV.

Comment: If you're using a HashSet, are you sure you have correctly overridden the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of `AbstractModule`, or otherwise left them both with the default implementation?

Comment: I did not implement `equals` nor `hashCode`, which should be fine afaik? And I tried `ArrayList` with the same results.

Comment: Yes that would be fine. Still, I can't reproduce your problem with the part of the code you've shown.

Comment: This bug was fixed in eclipselink v2.6.0. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Boann did, I tried running your code (filling in simple implementations for classes you haven't shown the code for (`LV`, `AbstractModule`) and initializing `lv`) and I get the expected result:

```
2
before:short2
2
in map:short2, in map:short1
short2, short1
2
```

So, my assumption is that the problem isn't in the code you have shown here, but in the code for either LV or AbstractModule, or perhaps you aren't importing the classes you think you are. Finally, can I assume there is no other thread running that could be changing the `ams` collection?

*For comparison, this is my dummy implementation of your classes.*

AbstractModule:

```
public class AbstractModule {

    String kurzbezeichnung;

    public AbstractModule(String desc) {
        this.kurzbezeichnung = desc;
    }

    public String getKurzbezeichnung() {
        return this.kurzbezeichnung;
    }

}
```

LV:

```
public class LV {
    HashSet<AbstractModule> ams;

    public LV(HashSet<AbstractModule> abstractModules) {
        this.ams = abstractModules;
    }

    public Collection<AbstractModule> getAbstractModules() {
        return ams;
    }
}
```

initialization:

```
HashSet<AbstractModule> initialAms = new HashSet<AbstractModule>();
AbstractModule short1 = new AbstractModule("short1");
AbstractModule short2 = new AbstractModule("short2");
initialAms.add(short2);
initialAms.add(short1);
LV lv = new LV(initialAms);
```

**EDIT**:

After seeing your updated question, and realizing that all these classes are in fact persistent database Entities, I think that the problem may be due to lazy loading. Could I suggest that you change your definition of ams to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lv", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<AM> ams = new HashSet<AM>();
```

As you can see from the discussion below, it turns out that EclipseLink implements the ams collection as an `org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectSet`, which is a lazily loaded implementation. But that class does not implement the `stream()` method.

As the OP has noted, there is a bug report against EclipseLink to get this fixed:  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433075

Comment: Thank you, for your reply! There is no other Thread running. The original classes are basically POJOs and marked as Entities managed by JPA/eclipselink. I wrote dummies as well and could not confirm my error (basically I implemented exactly those dummies you showed). Hence, I assumed there must be another part that influences behaviour, but I could not track it down. But I found, that using a normal for loop works fine. Which makes no sense at all. So I am really confused and asked SO in hope that someone experienced something similar.

Comment: @Stuck Step-debug through the code, including the java.util classes, to find out what's going on. If that doesn't weedle out the problem, make a copy of the project, then hack away at it removing parts until the problem disappears, to create the most minimal code that does reproduce the problem, then post it here.

Comment: Sorry, I now found time to give a full example (see update in first post)

Comment: Now I see that theses are entity classes, I updated my answer.

Comment: Eager fetching is not a general solution to it. Especially, after calling size() on the collection, it is loaded and the stream should contain the elements.

Comment: _And yet it does not._ I'm afraid I don't know enough about eclipselink to know what it's doing under the covers. Could it be subclassing HashSet in order to provide lazy loading in which the count of elements can be fetched without fetching the actual elements themselves?

Comment: Could you check the runtime type of ams, and confirm that it is not an `org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectSet` and that it is a HashSet?

Comment: Hey, it is indeed `org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectSet`

Comment: Thank you, here is the bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433075 Maybe you can udate your answer so it contains the info that it is the indirectset runtime-type. Thanky you for the hints!